# String " vs char ' in TS, why is this an Issue again

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

My background is 30+ years, I'm used to using " for strings and ' for chars, it comes natural for me.

I stayed out of the PHP wars on " vs ' so, lets *not* raise that issue.

I'm using Typescript, and TS lint is insisting ' instead of ", sure, I can turn it off, but maybe there is a reason in TS compilation? Other than my co-workers env, will it cause problems? why is TSLint insisting?

Comment: There is no `char` type in Typescript; either double-quotes or single-quotes define a string literal, since that's how it works in Javascript.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can configure it on your tslint config. Just define one standard and stick to it.

Comment: TSLint (which is deprecated, by the way) is *configured* to insist based on choices of the person who set it up. You should conform to the team's standards.

Comment: If you have it setup to auto-fix that stuff on save, then it doesn't matter which one muscle memory makes you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referring to the TSLint [`quotemark`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/quotemark) rule. You can configure it in your `tslint.json` to prefer whichever quote style you prefer.

There's no real language level benefit to using one quote style over the other, but having a single consistent choice in your project can be pretty useful to keep a consistent style.

By the way, [TSLint is deprecated](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534), and you'll be better off in the long run using [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io) to lint your TypeScript code with ESLint.